# How to setup influxDB

Tags: sql, influxdb

I found influxDB but really there  isn't that many sources other than there website. I am trying to push my networks info to the Database every 30 seconds. how can i just add columns without any points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need and no way to define columns or series up front, just write the points and the series will automatically be created.

Comment: so if i want to build and monitor something and talk with influxdb it will automatically create the series. say for instance i build a small weather station that records temperature in my area and talk with the DB.

Comment: Yes, all series are automatically created when the first point is written to them.